# Why do both handles on jQuery slider show minimum value?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have a jQuery slider defined as follows:

```
    $('#price-slider').slider({
      min: 7,
      max: 16,
      animate: true,
      range: true,
      step: 10,
      values: [7, 16]
     });
    $('#price-slider').slider().slider('pips');
```

When it renders, there is only one handle, and the min/max values are both equal to the defined min value of 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slider doesn't move because you have min and max values 7, 16  and step is 10 ??

So you need to change step, say to 9  or change min, max values...

See working code:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
  
    $('#price-slider').slider({
      min: 7,
      max: 16,
      animate: true,
      range: true,
      step: 1,
      values: [7,16]
     });
    $('#price-slider').slider().slider('pips');
    
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="price-slider"></div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah! I had expected a slightly different behavior given those original values, that the slider wouldn't move, but that it would still show two handles and the min/max values rather than one handle and the min value being used as both min and max. Thank you!